# Should I use assert(true) in junit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing

For junit tests where I am just testing if something works correctly, should I use assert(true)? Since it is legacy code, it is difficult to get a good assert statement.

Comment: I smell an XY problem. You should pick up a copy of Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers.

Comment: What exactly do you think this will accomplish?

Comment: Not unless your goal is to test the correctness of the Java compiler and runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you were to use assert(true), your always going to pass the test because True is always True.

If you want to test that it fulfills a condition using True/False, use something like assertTrue or assertFalse.